# I can't display the data from an API into a FlatList, but I see it in my console.log. What is the problem?

Tags: json, react-native, api, axios, react-native-flatlist

Console logging my react native app shows the data I fetch from an API. The problem now is that it is not displaying in the FlatList.

```
const HealthLinkMain = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(API_URL, {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
                    },
                });
                setData(response.data)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Test</Text>
            <FlatList
                data={data.data}
                renderItem={(item) => (
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.clinic_name}</Text>
                        <Text>{item.clinic_address}</Text>
                    </View>
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.clinic_name}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: Where did you have added console and add styles code as well in question

Comment: under the setData(response.data) I added console.log(response.data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be in your renderItem as you haven't destructured the item, try this:

```
    renderItem = {({ item }) => {
       return (
        <View>
            <Text>{item.clinic_name}</Text>
            <Text>{item.clinic_address}</Text>
        </View>
       )
    }}
```

You can also seperate it the renderItem into a function of it's own which a lot of people tend to do:

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
     return(
            <View>
                <Text>{item.clinic_name}</Text>
                <Text>{item.clinic_address}</Text>
            </View>
     )
}
```

and then change the flatlist calling function accordingly:

```
            <FlatList
                data={data.data}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.clinic_name}
            />
```

Comment: i tried this and it's still not rendering any data to the FlatList

Comment: @Rnwck I edited the answer to include another solution, if it's not getting rendered now then it's probably a styling issue.

Comment: Thanks, separating the renderItem had it working. I forgot that it is possible to separate it. Thank you, it worked.